# Varnishadm configs

Tags: varnish

How I can keep configurations for varnishadm? I asked because after restart varnish lost data about configs which I declared.

```
varnish> vcl.load my_config /etc/varnish/my_config.vcl
200        
VCL compiled.

varnish> vcl.label my_config_test my_config
200        

varnish> vcl.list
200        
active      auto/warm          0 boot
available   auto/warm          0 my_config (1 label)
available  label/warm          0 my_config_test -> my_config



 root@dev:/var/lib/varnish/wujek# /etc/init.d/varnish  restart
[ ok ] Restarting varnish (via systemctl): varnish.service.


varnish> vcl.list
200        
active      auto/warm          0 boot

varnish>
```

I thinking how **varnishadm** keep configuration for **boot**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I run the server using to command

> varnishd -I start.cli -F -a :80 -f ''

https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/one-vcl-per-domain